# Linking of OPC UA and DDS - How to integrate?

Tags: communication, opc, data-distribution-service, industrial

I have read that there might be some specification on the integration of OPC UA and DDS within "OPC Foundation's DDS OPC UA Part 14". Can somebody tell me how to find this specification or where it has been released? Through the website of the OPC Foundation, only Part 1 - 13 can be found... Thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition to the effort that you mention, there is an OMG RFP called "OPC-UA/DDS Gateway", you can find it [here](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?mars/15-09-02). It does not depend on this new Part 14 of the UA spec. Which of the two approaches is better for you depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPCUA Part 14 is a new part that focuses on "Publish Subscribe". I think it is not finalized yet so it is only available to members of the OPC foundation.

There has been discussions within the OPCUA working group of making DDS one of the "Communications models" for OPCUA Pub-Sub. As far as I know the OPCUA working group has still not made a decision whether to go forward with this. If it is done then it may be included in OPCUA Part 14 or be defined in a separate document.

If you have an opinion or use-case for this I think this is a good time to voice it because it may very well influence what the OPCUA working group does.

-Gerardo

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I already thought something like that might be reason, why you cannot find the actual Part 14. I am just a little confused, as the OPC Foundation is talking about the Pub Sub specification for more than a year now, and they don't seem to make a lot of progress.

Answer (score 0):

There are already prototypical implementations, e.g. by Unified Automation and Softing. It is a PubSub approach, but not exactly a reimplementation of DDS. I witnessed a presentation at the tttech forum last autumn. 10ms cycle time is feasible. Especially in conjunction with TSN switches this approach allows to go deeper into the fieldbus area. But UA keeps it's versatility as an integration framework for non-realtime applications.